# How to check if an Android application is started by a user or another application

Tags: android

Is there a way for Android to check if an application is started by user or by another application/system? For example, an application provides a service or is registered as a content provider. When it is started, I need to know if it is launched directly by interactive user, or via startService, or by ContentResolver. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can put some extra data (bundle) into the `Intent` which starts your app. Different type of values in your extra data will allow you to figure out which service (or whatever) has started your app.

Comment: Ok, if I use the app as a content provider or a service I do not start it by intent, but by ContentResolver or startService. Is there a way to check this situation?

Comment: every application in android starts via `Intent`s. Services almost starts via `Intent`s. Even `startService` method takes `Intent` as parameter (`startService(Intent)`).

Comment: yes, you're right about service, but I'm not aware of how to pass extras via content resolver; though I can still invoke a content provider by intent, it's not useful in my case.